# Google App Engine Algolia Indexing Error

Tags: google-app-engine, go, algolia

I’m using Google App Engine for a golang api with algolia and I’ve been working (indexing records) without any issue in localhost, today I deployed to test it live and I got this error for all my indexing operations

Cannot perform request [POST] /1/indexes/INDEXNAME/batch (APPID.algolianet.com): Post https://APPID.algolianet.com/1/indexes/INDEXNAME/batch: dial tcp: lookup APPID.algolianet.com on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: socket: operation not permitted

Any solution ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with setting up algolia with app engine in production, you have to set up a different transport for the algolia client... here is it:

```
client := algoliasearch.NewClient(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY)
    transport := &http.Client{
        Transport: &urlfetch.Transport{
            AllowInvalidServerCertificate: true,
            Context: appengine.NewContext(r), // r *http.Request
        },
    }
client.SetHTTPClient(transport)

client.initIndex(INDEX_NAME)
```

EDIT:

This is now fixed by golang 1.11 release, you can simply use algolia golang as is